# Import a json file in typescript without building it

Tags: json, typescript

I have a json config file for validating a form. It's generated from a base file. It's sent to the frontend for client side validation and imported in the backend for server side validation so that the validation matches.

My ideal file structure/files would be

```
|
|-dist
  |-validation.js
|-generated_files
  |-validation.json
|-src
  |-validation.ts
```

validation.ts

```
import validationObject from '../generated_files/validation.json
```

validation.js

```
const uppeak_json_1 = __importDefault(require("../generated_files/validation.json"));
```

However the typescript compile does the following

```
|
|-dist
  |-generated_files
    |-validation.json
  |-src
    |-validation.js
|-generated_files
  |-validation.json
|-src
  |-validation.ts
```

validation.ts

```
import validationObject from '../generated_files/validation.json
```

validation.js

```
const uppeak_json_1 = __importDefault(require("../generated_files/validation.json"));
```

I know that what's generated works, however it would be nice to be able to regenerate the json file without rebuilding the typescript.

I know that instead of rebuilding the typescript I could just copy the "generated_files" folder into "dist" when it's regenerated or after the typescript compile I could simply move the "dist/src" folder to "dist".

But ideally the typescript compile would leave the "generated_files" alone and just point at them.